# Can't return a value from map iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having problems when trying to return a value encountered from a .map using Javascript. There's my code:

```
function LineaDeSuccion() {
  const carga = vm.cargaTotal / vm.numeroEvaporadores;
  vm.succion.map(i => {
    if (i.temperatura == vm.tempSel) {
      const cargas = Object.keys(i).map(function(key) {
        return i[key];
      });
  // I need to return this value in my function
  return getKeyByValue(i, closest(cargas, carga));
  }
  // Obviously I can't do it because the value it's encapsulated into the map callback.
  // How can I solve it?
  return value;
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `Array.prototype.find` to find the value you want in the array, then perform the transformation you need once you have it.

```
function LineaDeSuccion() {
    const carga = vm.cargaTotal / vm.numeroEvaporadores;
    const i = vm.succion.find(i => i.temperatura == vm.tempSel);

    if (i === undefined) {
        throw Error("can't find what I want in the array");
    }

    const cargas = Object.keys(i).map(function (key) {
        return i[key];
    });

    return getKeyByValue(i, closest(cargas, carga));
}
```

Note that this approach will not iterate over the entire array but break out of the `find` loop immediately once a match is found. If there are several elements `i` in the array which satisfy the condition `i.temperatura == vm.tempSel`, this will return the first match, not the last.

Comment: This works for me. The other solution brings me undefined in return.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value outside of your `map`, you'll have to set a variable that lives outside of your `map`, and then set that value within your `map`:

```
function LineaDeSuccion() {

    const carga = vm.cargaTotal / vm.numeroEvaporadores;

    let value = "defaultValue"; // default value

    vm.succion.map(i => {

        if (i.temperatura == vm.tempSel) {

            const cargas = Object.keys(i).map(function(key) {
                return i[key];
            });

            value = getKeyByValue(i, closest(cargas, carga)); // new set value
        }
    });

    return value;
}
```